# init block in struct

Tags: init, vala, genie

I read this line from
**init Block**
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Genie#init_Block

> An init block declared outside of a class or struct is equivalent to a
>   "main" function in C and only one of these may be present.

that say, we can declare an init block in class or struct.

Yes! We can write an init block in class, 
But how?

a construct works fine:

```
[indent=4]

struct Asd
    A: string
    construct()
        A = "123"

init
    var a = Asd ()
    print a.A
```

when I replace **construct** to **init**, it dosen't work!

How to write an init block in struct?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Please give explicit error messages.

Comment: Also please add the code that leads to the error message.

Answer (score -2):

Get rid of the `()`.

See https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Genie#Constructors for an example.